# How to fix Error 7965 when working with recordsets in VBA?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2013

I am working with a subform in VBA (ms access 2013).  I am trying to load 2 text boxes with data returned from a stored procedure (SQL-Server v17.9.1)  When I run the proc in Management studio I am getting 3 rows returned there are only 2 columns the employee's initials and the total number of their clients.

When I attempt to set the form's recordset (Set Me.Recordset = rst) to the record set returned by my query I get the following error:

> "Error 7965: The object you entered is not a valid Recordset property."

This is an existing access database (2013), my company wants to keep the Access Forms as the front end, but pointing all data and operations to a SQL-Server (V17.9.1) database.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strError As String
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open gconConnectOLEDB
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "spGetInitialsAndCounts"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Set Me.Recordset = rs  '<---- This is where the error is occurring
    Me.Rep.ControlSource = "Rep"
    Me.CountOfRep.ControlSource = "CountOfActiveClients"

Exit_Handler:
    On Error Resume Next

    If LenB(strError) Then
        MsgBox strError, vbCritical, Me.Name & ".Form_Load"
    End If

    If Not(rs Is Nothing) Then
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If

    If Not(cnn Is Nothing) Then
       If Not(cnn.State = adStateClosed) Then cnn.Close
      Set cnn = Nothing
    End If

    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
   strError = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

What is most frustrating is that similar code is used in other forms, and the text boxes are populating correctly.

Thank you for any help and insights you may provide.

Comment: There are many types of recordsets (DAO, ADO, ADO.NET). AFAIK, Access 2013 is using DAO (not ADO).

Comment: So how do I convert the SQL Server ADO Recordset to DAO?

Comment: @RazvanSocol: Access supports ADODB.Recordsets for forms (but not for reports, except ADP's)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of researching, it ends up that the "CursorLocation" property of the ADODB Recordset needed to be set to adUseClient.  The "CursorLocation" property can be set to either "adUseServer" or "adUseClient".  In my case, I wasn't specifying a value for it at all, and it was defaulting to adUseServer.
A snippet of my corrected code is below:

```vb
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open gconConnectOLEDB

With rs
  Set .ActiveConnection = cnn
      .Source = "EXEC spSQLServerProc "
      .LockType = adLockOptimistic
      .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
      **.CursorLocation = adUseClient**
      .Open
End With
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

Comment: Help yourself and you'll get helped! Nice, but add the link to the source, where you found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft allow [binding forms to ado recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/activex-data-objects/bind-a-form-to-an-ado-recordset) 
so I suspect your recordset return nothing. 
To check this use this code

```
 if rs.EOF then
    debug.print "empty recordset"
 else 
   Set Me.Recordset = rs  '<---- This is where the error is occurring
 end if
```

so if you get empty record try find out why the stored procedure return 3 rows and the adodb nothing.
The first check will be is gconConnectOLEDB  a valid connecting string ?